# Heroku Git Deployment Issues

Tags: git, heroku

Alright, even though I pushed my key to Heroku, I get public key errors!
The only thing else I would have is this:
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
(venv)mini-mac:enviro-heroku amyohara$ git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Now I just realized something, No repo. But still, I have not Idea what is going on with the keys? Denied? Would I have too add keys to the remote myself? (Even though I've been to github hq and used github a lot, I'm sadly still learning git :(

Comment: Nevermind... Now I only Have the Permisson Diened Promblem...

Comment: You should consider deleting this question, then.